# Incorrect Nuget Reference to System.ComponentModel.Composition when I am adding System.Runtine 4.3.1

Tags: c#, azure, dll, nuget

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019 and when adding nuget package for **System.Runtime 4.3.1** it automatically adds reference to **System.ComponentModel.Composition** . Though build is successful on my local machine, it fails on Azure VM when pipeline runs. Azure VM does not have Visual Studio installed it uses MSBuild. I did search it and read similar question answer but didn't help. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the problem here? Nothing prevents you to install `System.ComponentModel.Composition` using Nuget

Comment: please add `nuget restore` command on your pipeline. And since the issue is related to Azure, you should add azure tag.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski My question is "Why on the god's name "System.ComponentModel.Composition" is getting added when I am adding System.Runtime's nuget package?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Your comment is upvote worthy, the other one is not. Thank You. I have added azure tag. nuget restore command is already there in pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure exactly why `System.Runtime` needs to add reference of `System.ComponentModel.Composition`, but I can confirm from my testing that while installing `System.Runtime` nuget it adds a reference of `System.ComponentModel.Composition` from GAC, but does not add that nuget. Hence it is failing in machine where it's not present in GAC. So, to fix your error just add the nuget [`System.ComponentModel.Composition`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Composition/) explicitly in your required project.